# for loop iteration-population conflict

Tags: python, matlab, for-loop, indexing, populate

I am new in python and I am trying to learn it by myself. I am currently working on a code, which gives me index error because somehow for loop does not populate my data. I am supposed to iterate a value and with it, I depend on the previous value to produce the new value. Normally this was easy with matlab, only with x(:,k) but python does not work the same way and I will really be grateful for any help that does not judge my level of knowledge in python. Here how it goes:

```
x = np.matrix([[1.2],[.2]]) # prior knowledge
A = np.matrix([[1, 1], [0, 1]])
B = np.matrix([[.5], [1]])
U = -9
t1 = range(1,100,1)
for k, val in enumerate(t1):
      x[:,k] = A*x[:,k-1] + B*U
```

To my understanding, the error 'IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1' pops up because the for loop does not populate the data 'x' and therefore, there is no value for neither 'k-1' nor 'k'.

What I should do is to iterate and store 'x' values and pick the relevant previous value each time to obtain new value with given equation till the end of loop. As you can see, I have a column matrix and I should have a column matrix each time. I hope I could make myself clear.

Thank you

Comment: Why are you enumerating over a range? The results of your operations will give you arrays with shapes (2,1), but you are trying to index well past that: into up to 99. That is why you are getting an index error. It is unclear to me what you are trying to accomplish. Perhaps if you tell us that, and tell us what you are trying to accomplish with each of those lines, I think we could help you understand where it is going wrong

Comment: I think what you want is `x = np.concatenate((x, A.dot(x[:,k-1]) + B*U),axis=1)`. When you index into an array, e.g. `x[0]`, that's for accessing an element, not for growing an array. Note, this is going to be very inefficient in `numpy`.

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for your reply. The first line is the initial value of x, the second, third, fourth and fifth lines are the values that are used in for loop to calculate iterations for x. I actually changed the code so many times, I don't know why I used enumerate but you are right, I can simply use 'for k in range(1,100,1) instead. I will correct that. What I am trying to implement is code for kaman filter in general. In this system, the current value x(k) is calculated with previous value x(k-1) with given equation x(k) = Ax(k-1) + BU.

Comment: Each x(k) value becomes x(k-1) in next iteration until loop is executed. Here, I am expecting to have (2,k) matrix after every loop because record of values are essential for other calculations. And to use the previous value in current value, I need to access to (k-1)th value. I hope it is clear now. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Check out my second comment. That should fix what you are trying to do. Also, *add these details to the question, don't add them to the comments*.

Comment: That is definitely the solution. Thank you very much. I am also new at the website and I don't know how to edit my question but is it okay to keep it this way for this instance? Thank you very much again for your reply.

Comment: Don't use `numpy.matrix`, use `numpy.array`.  Numpy matrices are poorly-supported by most tools, the python community has standardized around arrays.

Comment: At first I used numpy.array but it gave me error until I replace it into numpy.matrix. I could not figure out my fault at the time but I hope I will do with time when I start understanding how Python operates. But thank you very much for the tip. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The first line is the initial value of x, the second, third, fourth and fifth lines are the values that are used in for loop to calculate iterations for x.

What I am trying to implement is code for kaman filter in general. In this system, the current value x(k) is calculated with previous value x(k-1) with given equation x(k) = Ax(k-1) + BU. Each x(k) value becomes x(k-1) in next iteration until loop is executed. Here, I am expecting to have (2,k) matrix after every loop because record of values are essential for other calculations. And to use the previous value in current value, I need to access to (k-1)th value.

The question was solved by juanpa.arrivillaga (https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) Thank you.